If "excess" motes are used for an effect that requires committing the motes, is the Essence User's mote cap effected?
In Exalted, there are a few ways for someone to temporarily gain motes in excess of their normal cap, such as Essence Lending Method (E3, p. 331). Normally, these motes dissipate if not used very quickly and the mote pool would simply return to its normal maximum.
But if the character uses the excess motes for something that then commits the motes, does that affect the maximum essence pool in the way it would if the character had committed them from the normal mote pool, or does it not since the the committed motes were above the maximum originally?
For instance, if Larry the Lender used Essence Lending Method to give Samuel the Swordsman 5 motes when Samuel's mote pool was already full and Samuel immediately uses those motes to attune an artifact, at the end of the next turn does Samuel have a full mote pool or is his mote pool reduced by 5?

I'm asking the question because I'm having a bit of a disagreement with someone and lacking a direct line to the designers, this seemed the best forum to get something close to a definitive answer.
I'm inclined to say that it doesn't work that way and committed motes reduce the mote pool of the person doing the committing. That seems to be the intention of committing and allowing ways around it too freely allows some major exploits. In particular, two characters with Supernal Lore, Essence Lending Method and Power Awarding Prana could really create shenanigans that seem to go too far even for Exalted.
But the other person reasons that the committed motes were excess and so don't reduce the later mote pool. The storyteller can police the worst possibilities for shenanigans, which is the storyteller's role particularly in a game like Exalted and limited usage of this is hardly overpowered when otherwise Essence Lending Method is rather underwhelming even for an E1 charm.
If the other person is right, it would have implications for ways to allow a mortal to use artifacts that require attunement among other things.

The core rules on Charm Duration states:

With the exception of permanent Charms, any Charm with
a duration longer than “instant” requires that any Essence
spent on it be committed. Committed Essence is “tied up”
for the listed duration of the Charm—it cannot be regained
until the commitment has been released.

And Essence-Lending Method:

If the target cannot accept all the motes transferred
by Essence-Lending Method he has until his next action
to spend them before they dissipate.

By a strict, literal reading, I'd say your cap is not affected
So from that we know that motes that are committed are spent the moment you commit them, and you have until your next action to spend the temporary motes before they disappear. By a strict reading, I'd say by RAW nothing happens when the committed motes would 'dissipate' to Essence-Lending Method's timeout, because the only 'ongoing' effect of Commitment is that you can't regain the motes. Of course, an ST could easily rule that the motes disappearing would end the Charm they were 'powering'.
It's definitely not intended
Commitment is meant as a trade-off to balance  both the better base stats of artifacts and a multitude of Indefinite Charms. Allowing a single Essence 1 Charm with no prerequisites to bypass the entire Commitment system for your circle is extremely unlikely to be intended by the designers or allowed by most Storytellers at their table.
As you say, an ST could only police the worst excess, but that's a nebulous line to draw. It might be more fruitful to just rewrite Essence-Lending Method if you feel it's underwhelming.

I think this makes perfect sense. It seems my belief is right under the rules as they were intended, but a strict literal reading might support my friend.
